# I want to print a random number every second , but nothing comes up?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   /* runOnUiThread th=new runOnUiThread(new TextChange());*/
    final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Random rand = new Random();
                int y=rand.nextInt(100);
                tv.setText(Integer.toString(y));

            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

if its a infinite loop then nothing shows up ever (it should have shown a new random number  each second) and if I initiate a finite loop only the last number show when the loop gets finished. How to show a new random number on screen every second?

Comment: This is not safe. The thread will still run even if you leave the activity

Comment: Try to change TextView value inside runOnUiThread() and first initialize Random .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to print a random number every second . Why does the program
>   crash?

Because `rand` object of `Random` is `null`. Initialize it before calling `nextInt` method:

```
rand = new Random();
int y=rand.nextInt(100);
```

**EDIT:**

Because accessing TextView from run method of Thread which will cause `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy...` so wrap :

```
tv.setText(Integer.toString(y));
```

in `runOnUiThread` method or use `Handler`.

Comment: thanks, now at least it show 1st number , but then again it crashed @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: says Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views and problem is in

Comment: tv.setText(Integer.toString(y));

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K can elaborate a bit more on runOnUiThread(), bcz i m not able to do it  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       
            public void run() {

                while(true)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int y=rand.nextInt(100);
                    tv.setText(Integer.toString(y));

                }
            }
        });

Comment: Didn't understand why anybody creates a thread just to make it sleep and dispatch all task on ui-thread. Use of handler does that without creating new thread.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int y=rand.nextInt(100);
```

Better way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Random random = new Random();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int y = random.nextInt(100);
            tv.setText(Integer.toString(y));
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
}
```

Comment: wont we need a runOnUiThread thing here to change the textview @subhash

Comment: Handler runs on same thread as it was posted so we dont need run on uiThread .Above code works, why dont you try it.